# CakePHP route regex not matching correctly

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, routes

After updating my CakePHP version from 2.2.2 to 2.6.2, one of my routes stopped working properly.

```
Router::connect('/articles/:keywords', array('action' => 'search', 'controller' => 'Articles', 'keywords' => null), array('pass' => array('keywords'), 'keywords' => '[A-Za-z0-9\+_]+'));
```

It takes input such as "World" and "World+News" through a url such as website.com/articles/World+News and passes whatever is after articles/ to the search function in the Articles controller. This was working fine up until the update. Now it will pass up the route and go to my "cannot find route" route if there is anything other than alphanumeric characters. It's like the regex isn't matching properly. e.g. "World" and "World123" will work but "World+News" will not.

Things I have tried:

1. Changing the regex to .* just to see if it works. It does.
2. Changing the route from :keywords to * just to see if it works. It does.
3. Trying something I know will fail such as excluding anything with letters in the match. It fails to use this route as expected.

I've been scouring everywhere, trying all sorts of regex combinations (the ones I have match successfully in the tester), and just generally trying to find out why this route will match but I cannot. This was working fine before the update and I can't find anything in the CakePHP documentation that would suggest why this isn't working. As far as I know the expressions have been right and I have confirmed that they fully match using a regex tester. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I can't solve your problem because I'm not familiar with CakePHP, but I can tell you two things. First, it's almost certainly not your regex pattern that's the problem. Unless CakePHP uses a very strange regex engine, that pattern should absolutely match "World+News". Second, your regex can be shortened quite a bit to `[\w+]+`. The `\w` is a character set that stands for all digits, letters, and the underscore character. Additionally, the `+` is treated as a literal when it appears within square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, we did try a combination like that (which worked), although we've left it as it has been since we know that worked and we're just trying to be careful. It's good to know that it's probably not the regex that is the issue. I'm hoping that someone who knows a bit more about CakePHP than I will be able to shed some light on this issue. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem *is* the regex, at least it's *part* of the problem.

In earlier versions, CakePHP passed the raw URL into the matching subject, which however was rather problematic, as it could require very ugly regexes, especially for non-ASCII characters. Now the URL decoded variant is being passed:

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../commit/d5283af818b59c5d96355d6e42bbd77e1322d8cb](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/d5283af818b59c5d96355d6e42bbd77e1322d8cb)**

So since `+` has a special meaning in URL encoding and actually stands for a whitespace, your regex won't match anymore. It's rather easy to fix, just match a whitespace instead of the `+`.

Comment: That was exactly what the problem was and it fixed it. Thank you very much!